# dynamically adding textarea data to a page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following jQuery code that gets all the text in a group of textboxes and then displays the text elsewhere on the page between "`<h2></h2>`" tags in a new `<div>`.

The code does work, but for some reason, it is adding an extra empty `<h2></h2>` to the end.

So, for example, if there are 3 textboxes on the page, it will display those 3, but then add an empty `<h2></h2>` to the end like this:

```
   <div id="desc1">
       <h2>description 1</h2>
       <h2>description 2</h2>
       <h2>description 3</h2>
       <h2></h2>    <!--why is this here?-->
   </div>
```

I can't figure out what's going on.  Could anyone offer any suggestions?

```
var newDiv = $("<div>").attr("id", 'desc' + counter);

var descriptions;
$(function () {
       descriptions = $('textarea.descriptionTxt').map(function () {
            return "<h2>" + this.value + "</h2>";
       }).get();
       $(newDiv ).html(answers.join(''));
});

$(newDiv).insertAfter(titleDiv).html();
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps your last description is empty? Try:

```
   descriptions = $('textarea.descriptionTxt[value!=""]').map(function () {
        return "<h2>" + this.value + "</h2>";
   }).get();
```

- http://api.jquery.com/attribute-not-equal-selector/

Comment: Is there a way of checking to see if the textarea is hidden or not in the DOM before adding it to the div?  (like display: none;)...thanks!

Comment: I ended up using textarea.descriptionTxt:visible